# How to implement opIndex for compile time indices?

Tags: d

```d
ref auto opIndex(size_t i){
   return t[i];
}
```

Here `t` is a tuple and `i` needs to be read at compile time. How would I express this in D?

Comment: I don't think you can have a compile-time `opIndex`.

Comment: did you try adding constness `inout ref auto opIndex(size_t i) inout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any clean way to do this with `opIndex` currently, for two reasons. First is simple - it isn't implemented. That would be relatively easy to fix on its own but there is a second reason - it adds serious context sensitivity to language grammar.

Consider this struct definition:

```
struct S
{
    // imagine this works, syntax is not important
    static int opIndex (size_t i) { return 42; }
}
```

Now what does the code `S[10]` mean? Is it a static array type of ten `S` elements? Or static `opIndex` call which returns `42`? It is impossible to tell without knowing quite a lot of context and in certain cases impossible to tell at all (like `typeof(S[10])`).

Somewhat relevant (unapproved!) idea: http://wiki.dlang.org/DIP63

Comment: I like that DIP... It seems like it would make it possible to overload `|` and use it to build discriminated unions in similar way how F# does it...

Comment: I was trying to implement it - got basic `opIndex` working but from there on it got very hard to fight existing semantic analysis structure of DMD. It may need some very serious changes in AST if it is ever to get done.